# Is it correct to use transient to return values derived from entity attributes?

Tags: java

Do you think it's a good code pattern to use transient in the entity to return values derived from other attributes of the entity or is there a pattern and better way to do it? Putting in the service for example?

For example:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Transient
    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + lastName;
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to put `@Transient` there. It has no effect. Its perfectly fine to have that method in the entity class

Comment: Thank you very much, I will continue to use it like this only without `@Transient`

Comment: When I don't put `@Transient` intelliJ shows error **for property-based access both setter and getter should be present**

Comment: Just an issue with IntelliJ. See [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-240844) for possible workaround. They use `@Embeddable`, but should be same issue